# Make the aws-sdk node_module available to my Azure DevOps Extension

Tags: azure-devops, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js, azure-devops-extensions

I'm trying to develop an Azure DevOps extension similar to the official [AWS Toolkit for Azure DevOps Extension](https://github.com/aws/aws-vsts-tools).

What I'm struggling with is the fact that the aws-sdk is 45MB in size, but Azure DevOps extensions are limited to a 26MB upload size.

How does the official extension get their references to the aws-sdk working? It doesn't exist anywhere in the [`vsix` extension package](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AmazonWebServices.aws-vsts-tools&ssr=false#overview) when I unzip it.

Has anyone else ran into this file size restriction problem before?

Comment: That's an interesting problem. In most other contexts, my immediate focus would be to determine if you can establish external dependencies, similar to how you'd approach this in a package management context such as NuGet. I know that VSIX files can depend on other VSIX packages, but that doesn't really help here since the aws-sdk exceeds the size limit for the VSIX. I'm curious what you discover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We limit VSTS extension sizes to 25 Mb (we can go up to max 100 MB)
>   and allow exceptions only in certain cases. We worked with the
>   publisher here to understand their requirement and increased the size
>   limit as an exception for their publisher.

Take a look at this similar question here: [The extension package size exceeds the maximum package size '26214400 bytes'](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/292454/the-extension-package-size-exceeds-the-maximum-pac.html)

Before increasing package size, Could you please optimize. Suggestions:

- Can the common dependences, if any, be stated once in the extension
  package?
- Fetch things at runtime or during install time rather that providing
  it within the package. Consider using the tool installer lib to pull
  tool dependencies at runtime. Using the lib offers benefits where the
  tool is cached by version so for private agents, it won't get
  downloaded every build. We made it a lib so it can be used outside of
  tool installer tasks. The one consideration, is the task will not
  work in disconnected scenarios (no internet).   That should just be
  in the description / docs for the task.
- Some customers have had good success with WebPack to tree shake their
  dependencies in their tasks.

If you still blocked, you have to contact our VS Marketplace Support Team and try to extend the limitation.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, I've tried implementing common dependencies by including node_modules at the root of my extension, and having the individual tasks reference said node_modules directory. This works on my localhost, but then when I run it in the context of Azure DevOps the module cannot be loaded properly. I'm not sure what Azure DevOps does to the extension directory structure, but it seems to alter it after upload or installation. Ideally I could use a single node_modules directory and share amongst all the individual tasks.

Comment: `I'm not sure what Azure DevOps does to the extension directory structure.` The files section in Extension manifest  where you reference any files you wish to include in your extension. You can add both folders and individual files. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/manifest?view=azure-devops#files `"files": [      
        {
            "path": "node_modules/vss-web-extension-sdk/lib",
            "addressable": true,
            "packagePath": "lib"
        }
    ]`

Comment: Hi PatrickLu-MSFT - no luck yet, I've been trying different permutations of your suggested shared library, but am not having luck at runtime within Azure. I can run `node index.js` on my local just fine, but within Azure I get the infamous `Error: Cannot find module 'azure-pipelines-task-lib/task'` error. Still stuck on trying to get two tasks to share the same node_modules.

Comment: Hi @tiny-rick-258 Thanks for the update, every task needs to carry it's full dependency tree (every task is self contained) even if there's multiple in one extension. Basically, before you publish your task you should run npm install and then you should include the node modules in the package that you are publishing. Take a look  for more details at this link: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-task-lib/issues/485 Hope it's helpful in your case.

Comment: Thanks @PatrickLu-MSFT, this has been frustrating as the official documentation optimization suggestions you listed in your answer above would lead me to believe the node_modules could be shared across tasks. Perhaps MS doesn't consider a node_module a common dependency in that context though. Your github link makes it clear that what I am trying to achieve cannot be done, thus I will create a single extension per aws-sdk task that I need to develop. Its a clunky solution, but a solution no less. Thanks again.

Comment: It is still a mystery to me how this extension works: https://github.com/aws/aws-vsts-tools considering they utilize the aws-sdk in many of that extensions tasks, perhaps they contacted microsoft and got the size restriction lifted.